# Entity Framework 5 - TPT Inheritance with double Columns (Database First)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

i use the EF5/VS2012 for my application. My old DB (Database first approach) has tables for inheritance, each table has a user and timestamp column, that are set with inserts and updates. A trigger write this informations in a loggingtable.

Sample:

**BaseTable**
   ...
   User
   Timestamp

**SpecializedTable**
   ...
   User
   Timestamp

If i try to create this structure in the EF Designer (TPT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293) i've got an ERROR 19 that tells me that my specialized type cannot have the fields user and timestamp because they are declared in the base type.

How could i resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need the columns in the specialized table, because the base table record and the specialized counterpart can be seen as one record. It would be redundant information which is always good to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your specialized tables have User and Timestamp column and you want to have parent entity encapsulating those properties you need to use [TPC inheritance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx), not TPT.